# t test for each regressor hypothesis (Beta=0) in multiple linear regression in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, linear-regression

I have a data table like this (table.b1):

```
    y   x1   x2   x3
1  10 2113 1985 38.9
2  11 2003 2855 38.8
3  11 2957 1737 40.1
```

i fit a multiple regression on this with :

```
fit <- lm( y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 , table.b1 )
```

now i want to calculate t statistics for testing hypothesis individuals Beta1=0, Beta2=0, Beta3=0 in R.

Comment: Use `summary(fit)`

Comment: thanks ! must see t value ? and when we reject H0 ? @ekstroem

Comment: All the information is there. May an introductory text on statistics would be a good place to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ekstroem mentioned: use `summary(fit)`.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  "y"  = rnorm(100),
  "x1" = rnorm(100),
  "x2" = rnorm(100),
  "x3" = rnorm(100)
)

fit <- lm( y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 , dat)

summary(fit)
```

The output is

> ```
> Call:
> lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = dat)
>
> Residuals:
>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
> -1.8146 -0.6099  0.0218  0.5469  3.1833 
>
> Coefficients:
>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
> (Intercept)  0.036911   0.099474   0.371    0.711
> x1          -0.008111   0.092547  -0.088    0.930
> x2           0.031866   0.089083   0.358    0.721
> x3           0.081973   0.101729   0.806    0.422
>
> Residual standard error: 0.9822 on 96 degrees of freedom
> Multiple R-squared:  0.008441,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.02255 
> F-statistic: 0.2724 on 3 and 96 DF,  p-value: 0.8452
> ```

The t-value you are looking for are there. Usually, we rather look at the p-value and reject the H0 if the p-value is smaller than a predefined value and call the variable (statistically) significant. In most cases this predefined (alpha-) value is 0.05 aka 5%. So in my example non of the explanatory variables are significant as their p-values are all above 5%.